# Node.js HTTP Server Stops Listening

Tags: node.js

I have an HTTP server setup on port 1338 to listen on the IP for the server.  This works just fine when I first launch Node, but for some reason I have run into issues where the server randomly stops listening.  I have checked the logs that Forever is collecting from my app including any uncaught exceptions.  Nothing shows up in the logs of having any error since startup.

My question is two fold.  What would cause the server to stop listening at random intervals?  Also what check should be running in Node so that I can log out the error that is causing the listener to stop?

Here is the code below for my HTTP Server.

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    var pathname = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
    var query = url.parse(req.url, true).query;
    var check;
    var responseData = '';
    if(pathname === '/healthcheck/ticket'){
        check = new Date().getTime();
        check = check - tickets.lastAction;
        if(check < 30000){
            responseData = "page ok";
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
            res.end(responseData);
        }
        else{
            check = check/1000;
            responseData = 'Last action taken by the Ticket Generator was ' + check + ' seconds ago';
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
            res.end(responseData);
        }
    }
    else{
        responseData = 'URL NOT FOUND!';
        res.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
        res.end(responseData);
    }
}).listen(config.eng.port, config.eng.host);
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the server doesn't _randomly_ stop listening at all, but you have to figure out what causes it to stop. I tried the code you've shown above and it never seems to stop listening (and nothing in the code suggests it would). Have you tried to console.log everything and tried to figure out what's the last instruction run before it stops listening? Also (this might be a stupid suggestion but I don't know exactly how forever works of the top of my mind) are you sure forever doesn't overwrite the logs when it restarts (in case it's caused by a thrown error)?

Comment: I've checked forever and it is just appending the logs.  It of course now hasn't happened today (sometimes takes a few days), but I will relaunch it with more console logging to show each step and see where it dies.

Answer (score 2):

You don't handle the case when `pathname` is not equal to `/healthcheck/ticket`. There is no else branch.

Hence, when your server gets called with other urls but `/healthcheck/ticket`, it never closes the `res` stream, as `res.end()` is never called.

After a while, your server runs out of (network) resources, and hence *seems* to hang (i.e., it does not react on new requests any longer).

The solution is simple: Provide an else branch, and call `res.end()` in it, and everything should be fine.

Comment: Sorry I do have a URL not found that I put in there, but as I was cutting out some pieces of code that the company doesn't want shown it got cut.  Updating the code now to better reflect handling the else.